# I need to split a file (for now text file) into multiple buffer C

Tags: c, file, sockets, buffer, fgets

i'm trying to read a file and split this file into multiple buffers.
This is what i came up with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define PKT_SIZE 2048;
#define PATH "directory of some kind"

int main() {
    char filepath[200] = PATH;
    FILE *packet;
    int size = PKT_SIZE;
    char *buffer[size];
    int i=0; 

    //OPEN FILE

    if((packet = fopen(filepath, "r")) == NULL){        //I'm trying with a txt file, then i'll change it to 'rb'
        printf("Error Opening File\n");
        return -1;
    }

    //READ FILE

    while(*fgets((char *) *buffer[i], (int) strlen(buffer[i]), packet) != NULL) {  //read the file and cycling insert the fgets into the buffer i
        printf("Create %d buffer\n", i);
        i++;
    }

    fclose(packet);
    return 0;
}
```

Now, when i run this program, i get a SIGSEGV error, i managed to understand that this error is definetly:

```
 *fgets((char *) *buffer[i], (int) strlen(buffer[i]), packet) != NULL
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: You should probably stick with `char* filepath = PATH` instead, as using a fixed-length buffer which is either wastefully big or too small and problematic.

Comment: The declaration: `char *buffer[size];` will declare an array of character pointers of size 2048.  I think what you really want is to have an array of size 2 of 2048 characters.  So, maybe your declaration should be this: `char[2][size];`

Answer (score 1):

```
*fgets((char *) *buffer[i], (int) strlen(buffer[i]), packet)
```

This line as several problems.

- `buffer[i]` is just an un-initialized pointer pointing nowhere.
- `*buffer[i]` is of type `char` you need to pass the `char*`.
- `strlen` is not returning the size of the buffer. It is undefined behavior here because you called it over uninitialized pointer value.
- Also dererencing whatever `fgets` is return is bad when the `fgets` returns `NULL`. It invokes undefined behavior.

There many solutions to this ranging from dynamic memory allocation to using 
`char buffer[size][MAXSIZE];`. If you go about this you can get input this way:

```
#define MAXSIZE 100
...
char buffer[size][MAXSIZE];
while(fgets(buffer[i], sizeof(buffer[i]), packet)!=NULL){...
```

Answer (score 0):

`char* buffer[size]` is an array of N `char*` pointers which **are uninitialized**. You must allocate memory to these before using them or your program will explode in a ball of fire.

The fix is to allocate:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
  buffer[i] = malloc(PKT_SIZE);
}
```

You're going to be responsible for that memory going forward, too, so don't forget to `free` later.

Allocating an arbitrary number of buffers is pretty wasteful. It's usually better to use some kind of simple linked-list type structure and append chunks as necessary. This avoids pointless over-allocation of memory.